# get invoice item using order_item_id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, invoice, items

I want invoice item data using order_item_id and I tried using

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceItemRepositoryInterface;
private function getInvoiceItemById($orderItemId)
    {
        return $this->invItemRepository->get($orderItemId);
    }
```

But i am not getting any data and instead i am facing an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceItemInterfacePersistor::__construct()
>   must implement interface
>   Magento\Sales\Model\Spi\InvoiceItemResourceInterface, instance of
>   Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Item given, called in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on
>   line 93 and defined in
>   /var/generation/Magento/Sales/Api/Data/InvoiceItemInterfacePersistor.php:58
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93):
>   Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceItemInterfacePersistor->__construct(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Item),
>   Object(Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceItemInterfaceFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection))

Answer (score 0):

This seems to an issue related to **DI** files.

Can you run the following command from the root of the magento project and check if this resolves your problem?

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: hi bluscience thanks for the reply but still no luck same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine

```
protected $invoiceItemFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\ItemFactory $invoiceItemFactory
) {
    $this->invoiceItemFactory = $invoiceItemFactory;
}


public function getInvoiceItemById()
{

    $orderItemId = 454;

    /*Get single invoice item data */
    $invoiceItem = $this->invoiceItemFactory->create()->load($orderItemId, 'order_item_id');
    $invoiceItemId = $invoiceItem->getId();

    /*Get collection invoice item data */
    $invoiceItemCollection = $this->invoiceItemFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $orderItemId);

    foreach($invoiceItemCollection as $invoiceItem){
        $id = $invoiceItem->getId();
        $invoicedItemqty = $invoiceItem->getQty();
    }

}
```